# He told me to order plainly or leave

Tags: riddle, wordplay, rhyme, language

> A shortened friend in German hell,
>   a youthful rose at speed of *c*.
>   I ask you, barman, can you tell:
>   What will my order likely be?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You may get served quicker if you ask for a

> Bud Light

A shortened friend in German hell,

> Bud short for buddy and in German hell is bright light, so a Bud Light

a youthful rose at speed of c.

> A youthful rose is a bud and c is the speed of light, also a Bud Light

Comment: nice job @Tom :) +1 in admiration!

Answer (score 5):

A shortened friend in German hell,

> Hitler, German, hated by many, thus hell

a youthful rose at speed of c.

> c=speed of light, 
> 1. he rose/ gained popularity quickly when he was young. 
> 2. perhaps Cathedral of Light? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cathedral_of_Light

I ask you, barman, can you tell:
What will my order likely be?

> Dead Hitler Cocktail 
> http://www.1001cocktails.com/recipes/mixed-drinks/300482/cocktail-dead-hitler.html

Comment: I'm not sure how the word you came up with for the first line makes sense with "shortened friend."